# assign event handler to a submit button throws SyntaxError: missing exponent error in Firebug

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Please refer to the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uv7ng/3/

I have written a JS function and would like to assign an onclick event handler to the submit button "edit-next" on line 466 by using the following statement

```
document.webform-client-form-100.edit-next.onclick = ( function() {
}
);

webform-client-form-100 is the id of the form (line 84)
```

But firebug throws a SyntaxError: missing exponent error and the event handler is unassigned.

I tried document.node-100.edit-next.onclick, I still get the same error
(node-100 is the id of the page on line 59)

I'm not sure how else should I refer to the Submit button. Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById):

```
document.getElementById("webform-client-form-100")["edit-next"]
```

Since the id is unique in the document anyway you can also use it directly:

```
document.getElementById("edit-next")
```

I don't completely understand the error, but `-` is used for subtraction which is why you need to put your id in quotes.

Comment: Firebug reports TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null in both cases

Comment: I even tried document.getElementById('edit-next'), I get the same error. Very strange. Infact other document.getElementById('other divs') return the respective DOM elements.

Comment: I figured out the script was executing before the document was fully loaded. So moved the script to the footer. Its working.